# How to stay logged in after firebase phone authentication?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

Firstly, pardon me if this a newbie question I am new to Android development.

I am building an app that has phone verification as the only authentication needed. I want the users to stay logged in once they create an account, until they explicitly call `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();`

Is this possible? If so, how can I achieve this? Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is happening by default. You don't need to do something special to keep your users logged-in. They will be logged-in until they sign-out explicitly. See here [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/start/).

To verify the state of the user you can use a `authStateListener` like this:

```
FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener authStateListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth auth) {
        FirebaseUser firebaseUser = auth.getCurrentUser();
        if (firebaseUser != null) {
            //Do what you need to do
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score -2):

Hope this will help you

1. Store the credentials in local SQLite database
2. Every time the user opens the app check whether the details are there in the database, if yes then allow him to use the app with the credentials
3. If he explicitly calls sign out clear the record in the database

Comment: No, absolutely do NOT store the user's credentials. Besides, Firebase does by default what OP is asking.